# SSAS joining fact tables with different time granularity

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, cube, msbi

I have two Measure Groups, one with time grain `year/month(YearMonthDim)`, the other with time grain `datetime(CalenderDim)`. Can I link the Month-grained fact to the `CalenderDimension` so I can make reports joined from both fact tables on the time dimension?

I just made a quick fix and added the `YearMonthDim` to the fact table with the `datetime` granularity. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term I was looking for was [Role Playing Dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/role-playing-dimension/).

I connected the second measure group on `Month` granularity with the `Month` attribute in the already existing `CalendarDimension` whose granularity is on days.

It now works like a charm.

Comment: Good job! Don't forget to accept your answer / close your question.